How to organize table functions, docs within includes folder?
I saw in the docs (Add table documentation and Reuse variables and functions with includes in Dataform) you can add table documentation to Dataform by creating a file in the includes/ folder.
Question: Is it possible to organize these files in subfolders inside the includes/ folder? I want to organize the file descriptions, functions, etc by the tables I am working on.
Example:
includes/table_1/docs.js
includes/table_2/docs_2.js
And how should I do the import into my .sqlx file? I tried using the name of the file but this only works if the file is placed directly in the includes/ folder (includes/docs.js). If I add another folder (includes/folder_1/docs.js) I cannot reference the file correctly. I also tried doing the import with the js module but I cannot use the values inside the config{} block for description and columns.
Thank you so much for your help!
I know that if my file is in includes/docs.js in my sqlx I can call it as
config: {
type: "table",
description: docs.description,
...
}
I tried importing the file with javascript, using the name of the file inside the folder, etc. But I cannot get the result I needed.

I managed to work this approach by using a single file in the /includes folder as a middleware between the file structure I wanted and the tables in /definition.
If it helps someone, here's an example of the file structure I'm using to solve this (if there are any other better ways I'd be glad to receive your comments.)
/Includes

config_file.js
folder1/
folder2/


-- file_1.js

Example of config_file.js:
const table_1 = { table_config, columns } = require("includes/folder1/file_1.js")

module.exports = {
    table_1,
};

Example of file_1.js:
const table_config = {
  DESCRIPTION: `DESCRIPTION OF TABLE 1`,
  ...
};

const columns = {
    user_id : `A unique identifier for a user`,
    age : `The age of a user`,
    ...
}

module.exports = {
    table_config,
    columns
};


With this, I can use it in the .sqlx file as:
config {
  type: "table",
  name: "table_name",
  description: config.table_1.table_config.DESCRIPTION,
  columns: config.table_1.columns
}

Hope it may be helpful for someone))

You can create the structure as you want, you do not need the config_file.js and then write the configuration like:
config {
  type: "table",
  name: "table_name",
  description: require('includes/folder2/file_1.js').table_config.DESCRIPTION,
  columns: require('includes/folder2/file_1.js').columns
}

